# Prove that PRE-WORK-POST is Turing Complete

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, turing-machines, logic

This is a homework question and I am trying to fully understand what I have to do and how to go about it. Therefore, I don't want full answers to the question.

The programming language PRE-WORK-POST is defined as follows:

> Let P, Q, R be LOOP Programs. Then "PRE P WORK Q POST R END" is a PRE-WORK-POST program, whereby PRE-WORK-POST starts of by executing the program P, then executes program Q until $x_0 \neq 0$ and then finally executes program R. Show that the program PRE-WORK-POST is Turing complete, where you have to prove that all WHILE, GOTO, Turing and $\mu$-recursive functions can be simulated by a PRE-WORK-POST program. (All input values of the program are in $x_1,..., x_k$. All other variables are initialised at $0$ and the output value has to be in $x_0$.)

Here's what I have understood. We have the programs P,Q,R and the programming language PRE-WORK-POST. We want to show that all WHILE, GOTO, Turing and $\mu$-recursive functions can be simulated by a PRE-WORK-POST program. Since GOTO $\equiv$ WHILE $\equiv$ Turing Machine $\equiv \mu$- recursive, it is enough to show that any of the four can be simulated using PRE-WORK-POST.  When the program starts, it first executes the program P (which is a LOOP program). It then executes Q until $x_0 \neq 0$ and then finally executes R.

Since P,Q,R are all LOOP programs and all LOOP programs either assign a value to a variable, increment a variable, execute one program after another $P_1; P_2$ or LOOP $x$ DO $P$ END. This means that I have to simulate GOTO, WHILE, Turing Machine or $\mu-$recursive using these four different options.

All that is clear but I'm confused about the actual execution of the program. If we don't assign a value to a variable and start using it, that variable gets assigned the value of $0$. So if we don't assign $x_0$ any value, it is automatically equal to $0$. So how can Q be executed?

I need help understanding how PRE-WORK-POST will work.