# How can I simulate nested WHILE loops in a theoretical programming language to show Turing completeness?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, computability, programming-languages, proof-techniques

PRE-WORK-POST is a theoretical programming language with the following structure, where P,Q and R are LOOP program:

$$\text{PRE} \ P \ \text{WORK} \ Q \ \text{POST} \  R \ \text{END}$$

First $P$ is executed. Then $Q$ is executed until $x_0 \neq 0$. Finally $R$ is executed. I have to prove that PRE-WORK-POST is Turing complete and I have chosen to prove that I can simulate any WHILE program through a PRE-WORK-POST program. I'm stuck on one of the tasks. Given that $P1$ and $P2$ are both WHILE program, then $P1;P2$ is also a WHILE program (by definition). How can I simulate this using PRE-WORK-POST? I'm not really sure how I can do this since LOOP programs don't allow for nested loops.

Comment: I will bet that you misunderstood LOOP (and also, your description of it is insufficient). Is there a source where we can have at the complete specification of LOOP? It does not seem to be the [Wikipedia page on LOOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOOP_(programming_language)).

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [Prove that PRE-WORK-POST is Turing Complete](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/133915/4287). Where the question has no answer either.

Comment: In our lecture LOOP has the basic programs of: 1) Addition and Subtraction, 2) P1;P2, 3) LOOP $x_i$ DO P END. WHILE is defined as being able to do everything LOOP can with the addition of WHILE $x_i \neq 0$ DO P END. I need to simulate all WHILE programs using a Pre-WORK-POST program. I have done everything except the nested WHILE loops. That's what I'm asking here.

Comment: And that's also the definition we are given in the exercise.

Comment: This is basically the [Kleene normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_T_predicate#Normal_form_theorem).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I’m pointing out that what you are tasked to prove is effectivelly a weaker form of Kleene’s normal form theorem. And I don’t think the strategy you chose is a fruitful one; what you should try instead is to make a step-by-step simulation of the WHILE program, where $Q$ does one step of the simulation.

Comment: I honestly tried to understand the article but it is beyond what I have learned.